# warn NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts

Tags: apache

When I reload apache the following message appears:

```
Reloading web server config: apache2[Tue Dec 30 10:24:04 2014] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts
```

I checked the **ports.conf** file and the configuration is as follows:

```
root@li277-183:/etc/apache2# cat ports.conf
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
# This is also true if you have upgraded from before 2.2.9-3 (i.e. from
# Debian etch). See /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/NEWS.Debian.gz and
# README.Debian.gz

NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Why appears the following warning and how can I fix it?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply Put: Apache is listening on 443 but there are no VirtualHosts (websites) defined on that port. (See `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

I have two solutions:

**Solution 1** - Enable the default SSL config (Preferred, less destructive)
Define a site on 443 (the easiest way is to run the following code):

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl 000-default-ssl
```

And restart apache

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

**Solution 2** - Unbind Apache from Port 443 
Comment out the "NameVirtualHost *:443" and "Listen 443" lines of `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` (For example, add a # symbol in from of those lines so the new ports config file looks something like:)

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # NameVirtualHost *:443
    # Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    # NameVirtualHost *:443
    # Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you dovy. Now I've understand the configuration. Simply Apache is listening on 443 but there are no VirtualHosts defined in sites-enabled on 443. Just a little trouble now, in the apache error.log I find this "[error] [client xxx.xx.xx.xx] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico".
I do this to solve this problem: "touch /var/www/favicon.ico". Is it a good solution?

Comment: These links maybe are helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11099560/3728901 and http://serverfault.com/a/364427

Comment: Just want to add that  NameVirtualHost *:443 should be before  Listen 443